# IOS: stop a method in its execution

Tags: ios, for-loop, touchesbegan

I have this code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

mouseSwiped = NO;
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

point =[touch locationInView:imageView];

[self openImages];
}
```

evrytime I touch screen it call "openImages" method;

```
- (void) openImages{
// some code....
for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 200; j++){
         //some code... 
        }                 
    }
 }
```

then you can see that "openImage" is a heavy method because there is a double loop where i open some uiimage (but it's not the problem).
My question is that: what I can do to stop openImages everytime I touch screen, and call it one more time (because if i often touch screen app crash).
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSOperationQueue` for this. Make `openImages` into operation which can be cancelled. On each touch you can get all "open image" operations from queue, cancel them and enqueue new operation.

**To elaborate:**

Make an instance variable for your queue and initialize it before doing anything:

```
imageOperationsQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
```

Operation can be implemented like this:

```
@interface OpenImagesOperation : NSOperation
@end

@implementation OpenImagesOperation

- (void)main {
    for (int i = 0; !self.isCancelled && i < 200; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; !self.isCancelled && j < 200; j++) {
            //some code...
        }
    }
}

@end
```

`openImages` method now looks like

```
- (void)openImages {
    for (NSOperation *o in imageOperationsQueue.operations) {
        if ([o isKindOfClass:[OpenImagesOperation class]]) {
            [o cancel];
        }
    }
    [imageOperationsQueue addOperation:[OpenImagesOperation new]];
}
```

Comment: Oooohoha, nice one! Would you use the outer for loop to check for isCancelled?

Comment: can you give me a link with an example? or can you post an example?

Comment: @Jonas Byström well that depends on what happens inside the loops. Without that knowledge I'd check `isCancelled` in both loops.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `!self.isCancelled`?